# How to make Coin tile disappear LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

This is the Code I use to get the Cell of a Tile so I can delete it.

```
public TiledMapTileLayer.Cell getCell(){
    TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(1);
    return layer.getCell((int)(body.getPosition().x * Constants.PPM / 32),
           (int)(body.getPosition().y * Constants.PPM / 32));
}
```

The problem is I have a coin in my Bo2dWorld, which is 2x2 Cells big.

If I call this method it only deletes the Top-Right-Hand Corner Cell of the Coin Tile... But I want to delete all 4 Cells of the Coin. 
Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The coin is 2x2 tiles big and you only return on of those tiles in your getCell()

One option is to ad a property to the coin tiles in Tiled. Call it something like "CoinTileCorner". Then call the 4 tiles "TopLeft", "TopRight", "BottomLeft" and "BottomRight".

Now when you get a cell returned from getCell you can check for the property and know which other tiles to remove with it.

```
private void removeCoin(cell){
    String corner = cell.getTile().getProperties().get("CoinTileCorner");

    if(corner.equals("TopLeft")){
        //remove this cell, the cell to the right, below and the one bellow on the right. 
    else if(corner.equals("TopRight")){
        //remove this cell, the one to the left... and so on and so forth.
    }
}
```